# flyway + h2 in-memory db + hibernate + test causing table does not exist

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2, flyway

I am using h2 db for testing and I am using hibernate to create tables automatically but want flyway to insert scripts in the database. So, my flyway is not having create script.

Firstly I am not sure if this is possible or not. But when I am using some insert script my test is failing as flyway is not able to insert the record complaining that the table doesn't exist.

It seems it is trying to run the script much before than h2 is creating the table.

I am using spring boot to invoke the flyway. So, I just need this dependency and a db.migaration folder in the class path to activate the flyway:

```
<dependency> <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId> <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId> </dependency>
```

Any though would be great.

If you need more info, please do let me know.

If I add the create script for the various in the sql file, then it will work fine but I don't want to write create scripts. Rather I want to rely on hibernate to create it for me.

Thanks

Comment: I was strugling with the similar issue, check this out , maybe it will help you understand why your JPA Entities(tables) are not created [why my tables are not created / How can I validate which H2 schema my Spring boot app is working with?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560441/how-can-i-validate-which-h2-schema-my-spring-boot-app-is-working-with)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Spring Boot and I solved it by setting db url for flyway in test .properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:DBNAME
spring.datasource.username = sa
spring.flyway.url = jdbc:h2:mem:DBNAME
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you invoking flyway with Hibernate integrator (org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator)?

If so, Integrators are always executed before hibernate schema-export

The only way, as I've seen, to change the order is to add a SessionFactoryObserver then execute flyway migration

```
public class FlywayIntegrator implements Integrator {
    @Override
    public void integrate(Configuration c, SessionFactoryImplementor sfi,
                          SessionFactoryServiceRegistry sfsr) {
        sfi.addObserver( new SessionFactoryObserver() {
            @Override
            public void sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactory factory) {
                //now, after schema-export, flyway migration...
            }

            @Override
            public void sessionFactoryClosed(SessionFactory factory) {
            }
        } );
    }
//... other methods
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have added my approach to activate flyway in the main question.

Comment: How is the declaration on spring xml?

Comment: in spring boot, you don't need any xml file, just the above given dependency is enough to activate flyway.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how spring would integrate that.

You could use a different path and start it from Hibernate Integrator. But this wouldn't be that good

e.g:
Flyway flyway = new Flyway()
flyway.setLocations("classpath:db/migration_after_emf");
flyway.migrate();