# Why I can't find my tables in H2 schema / How can I validate which H2 schema my Spring boot app is working with?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, h2

I'm running a spring boot app

didn't have any  setting for h2 other than maven

when i'm connecting to the h2 console i can see the tables that were supposed to be created for two entities

i connected with the JDBC URL:  **jdbc:h2:mem:testdb**   (which is supposed to be the default)

Is there a way to make sure what schemas is H2 currently running/ or some log file for H2 ?

in my application.properties i have this:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
```

I read somewhere that H2 initializing itself upon login, but a demo i was watching these were the exact steps taken , so not sure that is the case.

these are the settings in the H@ console:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually saw the right schema all along

The reason I thought I wasn't seeing the right schema was - the JPA Entities I expected to see, were not there.

I then found that this was because I didn't name the package for the JPA entities correctly

I named it "domain" (see pic):

[image]

I should have named it `com.example.domain`  as can be seen:

[image]

This is because Spring Boot looks is doing a `@ComponentScan`  "under" the package with the main class , so I had to prefix the "domains" with the name of the package that the main class resides in, which is `com.example`.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly instruct spring boot to create and connect to a particular schema in H2 with config as below.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa
```

This creates a datasource of name test database in h2 in file mode. There would be a file called test.db in your home folder which would be the data file for the database.

DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT property decides to recreate the database on every restart.

Comment: Thanks dude, I've tried this already with identical results (not seeing the entities), anyway, i've found the issue

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way to tell Spring JPA the default schema for your H2 data source by just adding the **"SET SCHEMA {default schema}"** in the datasource url, e.g.:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS testdb\\;SET SCHEMA testdb
```

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to check the log when I run Sprinboot

```
jdbc:h2:mem:9967b201-6b59-4925-acb3-d2e50dc5d9a5.  --> this can be any other auto generated UUD
```

Adding this to your JDPC URL in the browser will let you see the tables that you created.

[image]